# How can I start a REPL that can access local variables in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop, deno

Just like `from IPython import embed; embed()` but for `node`.

I want to open a REPL shell programmatically and be able to at least read the local variables. Being able to change them as well is a plus.

Comment: by local variables you mean environment variables?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande No, I mean local javascript variables.

Comment: Hi, I think you if you need JS repl- you need to just write node command only [follow this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-console-repl)

Comment: I submitted a working example for `deno`, if you want it for `Node.js` let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a REPL similar to the built-in Deno REPL and and evaluate expressions using the [dangerous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function. Through it you'll be able to access local variables and other things (e.g. [`window`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#window)).

**repl.ts**

```ts
import { readLines, writeAll } from "https://deno.land/std@0.106.0/io/mod.ts";

export default async function repl(evaluate: (x: string) => unknown) {
  await writeOutput("exit using ctrl+d or close()\n");
  await writeOutput("> ");
  for await (const input of readInputs()) {
    try {
      const value = evaluate(input);
      const output = `${Deno.inspect(value, { colors: !Deno.noColor })}\n`;
      await writeOutput(output);
      await writeOutput("> ");
    } catch (error) {
      await writeError(error);
    }
  }
}

async function* readInputs(): AsyncIterableIterator<string> {
  yield* readLines(Deno.stdin);
}

async function writeOutput(output: string) {
  await writeAll(Deno.stdout, new TextEncoder().encode(output));
}

async function writeError(error: unknown) {
  await writeAll(Deno.stderr, new TextEncoder().encode(`Uncaught ${error}\n`));
}
```

**repl_demo.ts**

```ts
import repl from "./repl.ts";

let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = 3;

await repl((x) => eval(x));
```

**example usage**

```shell
% deno run repl_demo.ts
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> a
1
> a = 40
40
> a + b
42
```

Answer (score 4):

As far I know, the closest you can get is by using the `repl` built-in module (which is used by `node inspect` itself):

```
// ... your code you want to debug 

const repl = require("repl");
const replServer = repl.start({
    prompt: "Your Own Repl > ",
    useGlobal: true
});

// Expose variables
const localVar = 42    
replServer.context.localVar = localVar;
```

By running `node index.js` (assuming you saved the above content in `index.js`) we get access to this custom repl:

```
$ node index.js 
Your Own Repl > localVar
42
Your Own Repl > 
(To exit, press Ctrl+C again or Ctrl+D or type .exit)
Your Own Repl >
```

However, this does not work like a debugger tool, but really, it's only a REPL.

Comment: How do we automatically expose all local vars in the scope? Also, I think this method doesn't allow changing the local variables and then resuming the execution.

Comment: @HappyFace You will have to expose them, or create a utility function to expose them in an easier way. Indeed, this will not pause the execution of the script – for that you'd need to start a `node inspect` process with `debugger`s or breakpoints... I am just wondering why such a python-like utility would be needed in the first place – maybe we could find better alternatives. The command line Node.js debugger is quite good, and the IDEs have visual debugging interfaces too...

Answer (score 2):

For `deno` (Title says Node.js, tag deno) you can use `Deno.run` to execute `deno` and write to `stdin` and read from `stdout`.

The following will do:

```
const p = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["deno"],
    stdin: "piped",
    stdout: "piped",
    stderr: "piped"
  });

async function read(waitForMessage) {
    const reader = Deno.iter(p.stdout)
    let res = '';
    for await(const chunk of reader) {      
        res += new TextDecoder().decode(chunk);
        console.log('Chunk', res, '---')
        // improve this, you should wait until the last chunk 
        // is read in case of a command resulting in a big output
        if(!waitForMessage)
            return res;
        else if(res.includes(waitForMessage))
            return res;
    }
}

async function writeCommand(command) {
    const msg = new TextEncoder().encode(command + '\n'); 

    console.log('Command: ', command)
    const readPromise = read();
    // write command
    await p.stdin.write(msg);
    // Wait for output
    const value = await readPromise

    return value;
}

// Wait for initial output: 
// Deno 1.0.0
// exit using ctrl+d or close()
await read('ctrl+d or close()');


await writeCommand('let x = 5;')
let value = await writeCommand('x') // read x
console.log('Value: ', value)

await writeCommand('x = 6;')
value = await writeCommand('x') // read x
console.log('Value: ', value)
```

If you run that snippet, the output will be:

```
Command: let x = 5;
Command: x
Value: 5

Command:  x = 6;
Command:  x
Value:  6
```

There are some improvements to be made, such as handling `stderr` but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! I like this for other purposes than my question, but I don't think it answers my question; I want to use the REPL as a debugging aid. I need it to open in the middle of the normal javascript execution, not as a standalone process. I need the REPL to be able to access the local variables of the scope that runs it.

Comment: You want a debugger then.

Comment: I want an embeddable REPL that can also be used as a debugger. Is there such a tool available?

Comment: There isn't such tool available, you can check [Deno `debugger`](https://deno.land/manual/tools/debugger)

Answer (score 2):

This feature doesn't currently exist but is being proposed in https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7938.

The vision being something along the lines of

```
Deno.eval("Deno.repl()")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
//to be sure this context is here
const ev = eval.bind(this);
function ask() {
     rl.question('>', (code) => {
           console.log(ev(code));
           ask();
     });
} 
ask();
```

this code ask a input with readLine module and every time a reponse is provided the code is executed and a new input is askef

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.